# Setting up MDHA on VS2013

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-2013, installation, visual-studio-cordova

I've been working on setting up MDHA on VS2013 for a couple of days now. I've worked through many of the issues that others have had and I think this latest one is probably just another path issue which is what most of my problems have come down to.

My current error which I can't find anything on is:
Error   2   The command ""C:\Users\pc\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-mda\vs-cli" prepare --platform Android --configuration Debug --projectDir . --projectName "Hello" --language "en-US"" **exited with code 1**. C:\Users\pc\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-mda-targets\Microsoft.MDA.targets   182 5   Hello

You'll notice the Exit code on this is 1, previously I had exit code 8 and solved that by correcting the Java SDK and HOME environment variables.  Is there a list someplace that explains what each of the Exit Codes refers to? Or does someone know what Exit Code 1 is?

Thanks

Comment: I believe exit code 1 relates to an improperly configured version of node. Please uninstall and reinstall node to see if that fixes things.  You can refer to the [online documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn757054.aspx#ThirdParty).

Comment: Remove 'bld' folder in your application path, then try building again.